# What is the default chinese font in Android?

Tags: fonts

What is the default Chinese font in Android and where are they stored so that I can get the font files?

Answer (score 2):

On Android 9 it's [Noto CJK](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/), e. g. "Noto Sans CJK JP" font family (located in `/system/fonts/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc`). There is no `DroidSansFallback.ttf` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts are always stored at /system/fonts. By changing the system font to Chinese, and looking in that directory, you may be able to find the font.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the font is called [Droid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_fonts). A few variations (sans, sans mono, serif, condensed) are available from [DroidFonts.com](http://www.droidfonts.com/droidfonts/), though it should be noted that Droid Sans may be the only to contain Chinese characters.

> Each of the Droid fonts was custom designed by Ascender and optimized for on-screen legibility with the Android platform. ...
>
> [Droid Sans] contains over 43,000 glyphs and includes support for Simplified Chinese (GB2312), Traditional Chinese (Big 5), Japanese (JIS 0208) and Korean (KSC 5601). This font uses the Simplified Chinese ideographs for shared Unicode code points.

Comment: Droid is a family of fonts and your usual droid font doesn't have Chinese. Particular Droid font that has Chinese is DroidSansFallback from the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the font is DroidSansFallback.ttf it is located in /system/fonts/

Link to official droids page [Droid fonts family](http://www.droidfonts.com/droidfonts/)

> Support for CJK is provided by the Droid Sans "fallback" font. This font contains over 43,000 glyphs and includes support for Simplified Chinese (GB2312), Traditional Chinese (Big 5), Japanese (JIS 0208) and Korean (KSC 5601). This font uses the Simplified Chinese ideographs for shared Unicode code points.

There are no other font with Chinese in a regular western Android phone therefore DroidSansFallback.ttf is used to display Chinese.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. How did it solve the issue? Where to find it? What are the steps to perform? Please use proper English to the best of your ability. Consider following this guide: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)